# Why does my @font-face font work even when I delete the @font-face code, AND uninstall the font from my machine?

Tags: eclipse, css, font-face

I was messing around with `@font-face` and I had some weird results. I downloaded and installed the font and it got installed in /Users/myuser/Library/Fonts like it should (I suppose!?). The weird thing is that it was working whatever URL I gave it in CSS.

Now I have removed the `@font-face` class from the CSS altogether, emptied all possible caches, even disabled & removed the 'Garton' font from Font Book (Mac thingie), but it’s still working! (I’m developing and viewing the page in Eclipse.)

So...

1: how can it work? The only way to make it fail is when I edit the font-family 'Garton' in CSS. Whatever I write in `@font-face` it works and I have no duplicates in CSS! I restarted the computer, put it up in my PC where it fails. I looked in /Library/Fonts where default fonts are installed I suppose, and there is no 'Garton' there.

```
Works even without @font-face in css
#header{
font-family: 'Garton',Georgia, serif;
}

Only way to make it fail on mac
#header{
font-family: 'GartonXXX',Georgia, serif;
}
```

2: If ever get clarity in this, I guess I must install the font it on the webserver that’s hosting the page? Or is there another way?

3: Why do my downloaded fonts get installed in different folder than the default fonts? (Not so important, but I’m very confused.)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you’ve removed Garton from your Mac, it is odd that your web page still renders in Garton even without `@font-face` code. I can only imagine that Garton *is* still installed on your Mac.

   Questions regarding that are better asked at [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

   If you’re working with `@font-face`, it’s better not to install the font on your development machine, so that you see what normal users see.
2. Yes — to use Garton on a public web site (where people without Garton installed on their machines will view the site), you need to have the font file available on the site’s server, or via a font service like [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) or [FontSpring](http://www.fontspring.com/).

   You don’t need to actually “install” the font on the web server, you just need to serve the font file from there, just like you were serving an image file or a stylesheet, so that the browser can get it and use it on your web page.

   In order to get it to work across browsers, you need to have the font file in a few different formats, and be careful with your `@font-face` CSS to avoid tripping up Internet Explorer. The easiest way to get this right is to use [Font Squirrel’s `@font-face` generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).
3. Again, this is a question for [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks...for all good tips (site especially). For some reason eclipse jammed it all and kept the font in memory. When closing eclipse uninstalling the font and everything else is back to normal!

Comment: Aha! Thanks for following up on what caused the font to stick around after removing it, that’s good to know.